# Execute RDMSR and WRMSR instructions from C/C++ code

Tags: c++, c, cpu, masm, cpu-registers

I need to control C-State configuration. Specifically, I'd probably like to execute the following asm code:

```
__asm
{
    rdmsr
    and eax, 0x00
    or eax, 0x01
    wrmsr
}
```

Currently, I got this exception on `rdmsr` line:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x00e3139e in MessWithCStates.exe: 0xC0000096: Privileged instruction.
```

How can I (permanently) elevate priviliges of my app so it could execute the code above? I use VS 2010.

<strike>NOTE: It is possible without writing a kernel-mode driver. See *R/W Everything*.</strike>

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Despite your *NOTE*, I suspect this is not possible without writing a kernel-mode driver. [This page](http://www.mydigitallife.info/rw-everything-utility-free-download-to-access-and-dump-computer-hardware-info/) seems to imply that R/W-Everything uses a driver.

Comment: Yeah. It shouldn't be possible to do MSR changes from within Ring3. Theoretically it could be attacked in couple of ways beyond writing a driver - but it seems that creating a kernel driver (WDK) would be the easiest way to go.

Comment: Programs like that embed the driver in the EXE, expand and load it at runtime.  Classic SysInternals' trick.  RDMSR requires ring 0 privileges, only drivers get that.

Comment: I would agree that this cannot be done directly from user mode in any way. This will require a device driver.

Comment: Thanks Alex, Rob, qdot, Hans ans Omnifarious for interesting and accurate respones. I am going to learn more about writing kernel-mode drivers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chances are, you are running this code on an x86 processor within Ring 3. You do not have the privileges to execute this command. Period. This is a hardware limitation. The only way to execute that instruction is to go into Ring 0 and chances are, your OS won't let you do that. You will need to write a kernel-mode driver to accomplish this.

**Edit**: http://faydoc.tripod.com/cpu/rdmsr.htm has more info.

Comment: Thanks for enlightening me. Going to learn how to write a kernel-mode driver.