# Why are the data segment registers always null in gdb?

Tags: gdb, x86-64, glibc

Why do the data segment registers (ds/es/fs/gs) always seem to show up as 0x0 in GDB? For example, no matter what process or thread I look at, "info reg" always seems to give me output like this:

```
cs             0x33     51
ss             0x2b     43
ds             0x0      0
es             0x0      0
fs             0x0      0
gs             0x0      0
```

I am trying to debug glibc code where I see the fs segment prefix in the functions I am dissembling:

```
(gdb) disas __lll_lock_wait
Dump of assembler code for function __lll_lock_wait:
0x000000302800e240 <+0>:     push   %r10
0x000000302800e242 <+2>:     push   %rdx
0x000000302800e243 <+3>:     xor    %r10,%r10
0x000000302800e246 <+6>:     mov    $0x2,%edx
0x000000302800e24b <+11>:    xor    $0x80,%esi
0x000000302800e251 <+17>:    and    %fs:0x48,%esi
0x000000302800e259 <+25>:    cmp    %edx,%eax
0x000000302800e25b <+27>:    jne    0x302800e264 <__lll_lock_wait+36>
0x000000302800e25d <+29>:    mov    $0xca,%eax
```

I know that this is how glibc will reference the thread's TCB (tcbhead_t) for TLS and other important stuff. So wouldn't that mean that each thread would **need** to have a unique descriptor entry? Shouldn't each thread have a unique value for the fs register? I do not even believe 0x0 is a valid selector at all because the TI (table indicator) bit would indicate the GDT, and I thought there is no valid 0 GDT entry.

I know I must be missing something obvious, anyone know what it is?

Environment: CentOS 6.6, x86_64

Comment: See also: [Read `fs_base` MSR in gdb](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59125003/)

Answer (score 3):

> Shouldn't each thread have a unique value for the fs register?

No, each thread needs a unique FS segment base, but instead of requiring an LDT or GDT entry for each possible base, **there's a mechanism for the kernel to simply set the FS base address directly in the internal segment descriptor** without using a slower `mov fs, eax` instruction that loads a whole segment description including permissions and stuff.

The standard mechanism was writing an MSR (model-specific register); See [Detail about MSR_GS_BASE in linux x86 64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11497563/detail-about-msr-gs-base-in-linux-x86-64).

Intel since IvyBridge has supported the FSGSBASE feature, but apparently Linux is only just recently taking advantage of [the `wrfsbase` instruction](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/WRFSBASE:WRGSBASE.html), which is faster than the WRMSR method.  See https://lwn.net/Articles/769355/.

As well as being faster than `wrmsr`, `wrfsbase` has the added feature that the kernel can let user-space execute it, so VMs in user-space (like Java) could maybe take advantage instead of needing to make a system call for an always-privileged WRMSR instruction.

Answer (score 1):

> So wouldn't that mean that each thread would need to have a unique descriptor entry?

Yes.

> Shouldn't each thread have a unique value for the fs register?

No. The value of `fs` register is the same, but the memory it points to is different in every thread. See `arch_prctl(2)` [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/2/arch_prctl) and code for setting this up in [GLIBC source](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=sysdeps/x86_64/nptl/tls.h#l157).

Answer (score 1):

I think it's done by kernel:
Check the function start_thread_common(), then you will find the following:

```
    loadsegment(fs, 0); 
    loadsegment(es, _ds);
    loadsegment(ds, _ds);
    load_gs_index(0);
```

For x86 64, _ds is 0. Why _ds is 0, since it's completely useless. The following is from Intel SDM v3.

> 3.2.4 Segmentation in IA-32e Mode
>
> In IA-32e mode of Intel 64 architecture, the effects of segmentation depend on whether the
>   processor is running in compatibility mode or 64-bit mode. In
>   compatibility mode, segmentation functions just as it does using
>   legacy 16-bit or 32-bit protected mode semantics. In 64-bit mode,
>   segmentation is generally (but not completely) disabled, creating a
>   flat 64-bit linear-address space. The processor treats the segment
>   base of CS, DS, ES, SS as zero, creating a linear address that is
>   equal to the effective address. The FS and GS segments are exceptions.
>   These segment registers (which hold the segment base) can be used as
>   additional base registers in linear address calculations. They
>   facilitate addressing local data and certain operating system data
>   structures.